# Use kustomize to set hostPath path

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Is it possible to use kustomize to specify a volume hostPath from an env variable?

I have a Kubernetes manifest that describes my deployment consisting of a container.
During development, I use a different image (that contains dev tools) and mount code from my host into the container.   This way I can make code changes without having to re-deploy.

I'm using a patchStategicMerge to replace the production image, with the one I want to use during dev and mount the code into the container i.e.

kustomization.yaml

```
kind: Kustomization

bases:
- ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
- my-service.yaml
```

my-service.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
...
...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: myservice-dev-image:1.0.0
          command: ['CompileDaemon',  '--build=make build', '--command=./myservice']
          volumeMounts:
          - name: code
            mountPath: /go/src/app
      volumes:
      - name: code
        hostPath:
          path: /source/mycodepath/github.com/myservice
```

What I'd like to do is make the path configurable via an environment variable, so that I don't have to check my specific path (/source/mycodepath/) into git, and so that other developers can easily use it in their own environment.

Is it possible to do this with kustomize ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that with an environment variable but it is possible to define an overlay that has a different path. Check out Kustomize overlays. Here's one using overlays https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/springboot

Comment: am I right that your question can be stripped down to "how to mount local path (from my laptop) to the pod?" , additionally, where do you run the pod? do you run it on a standalone k8s , or is ita  k8s directly on your host/laptop/PC (minikube, etc) or is it a   managed one like  GKE, EKS, etc?

Comment: @Nick not quite.  I know how to mount a local path from my laptop.  The problem is on my laptop the path could be /users/bob/github/somecode and on a co-workers laptop its on /users/sue/github/mycode.    If I use an overlay I can define my path in the overlay.  But I don't want to check that into git.   In docker-compose we solve this by using a relative path, but that doesn't appear to work with k8s

Comment: @JustinTamblyn thanks.  I am using overlays.  The question is how can I create an overlay that different developers can share without having to modify the volume path.   Using either a variable or a relative  path would help.

Comment: @CoderJones I think I understand. I'll put something together as an answer

Answer (score 5):

Create following directory structure

- k8s
- k8s/base
- k8s/overlays
- k8s/overlays/bob
- k8s/overlays/sue

First we need to create the base. The base is the default template and it provide the bits that apply to both people. In `k8s/base` create a file called `app.yaml` and populate with the following (actually paste yours here. You can put other common bits in there too separated by a `---` and new line).

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: myservice
        app: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: myservice-dev-image:1.0.0
          command: ['CompileDaemon',  '--build=make build', '--command=./myservice']
          volumeMounts:
          - name: code
            mountPath: /go/src/app
      volumes:
      - name: code
        hostPath:
          path: /xxx
```

Next in the same directory (`k8s/base`) create another file called `kustomization.yaml` and populate with:

```yaml
resources:
 - app.yaml
```

Next we will create two overlays: one for Bob and one for Sue.

In `k8s/overlays/bob` let's create Bob's custom changes as `app.yaml` and populate with the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: code
        hostPath:
          path: /users/bob/code
```

Now also in `k8s/overlays/bob` create another file called `kustomization.yaml` with the following:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../../base
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - app.yaml
```

We can copy the two files in `k8s/overlays/bob` into the `k8s/overlays/sue` directory and just change the path in the `volumes:` bit.

Next we need to do a `kustomize build` to generate the resulting versions - bob and sue.

If the `k8s` directory is in your code directory, open terminal (with Kustomize installed and run:

```sh
kustomize build k8s/overlays/bob
```

That should show you what Bob's kustomization will look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice
        name: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - CompileDaemon
        - --build=make build
        - --command=./myservice
        image: myservice-dev-image:1.0.0
        name: myservice
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /go/src/app
          name: code
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /users/bob/code
        name: code
```

To apply that you can run:

```sh
kustomize build k8s/overlays/bob | kubectl apply -f -
```

To apply Sue you can run:

```sh
kustomize build k8s/overlays/sue| kubectl apply -f -
```

Yaml is sensitive about spaces and I'm not sure this will sit well in a Stackoverflow answer so I've put on Github as well: https://github.com/just1689/kustomize-local-storage